# How can I transform 'png' picture with resolution '28x28' to array (28, 28, 1)?

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network

I tried to do this:

```
import cv2

color_image = cv2.imread('numbers/1.png')
gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(color_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img_final = gray_image.reshape(28, 28, 1)
```

but I got (28, 1) array.

Comment: Try `cv2.imread('numbers/1.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE).reshape(28,28,1)`. If that's not working don't reshape just tell me what `.shape` gives.

Comment: For me, your code works. Are you sure there's an error or that you copied and pasted the code correctly?

Comment: @user2640045, when I dont reshape I got (28, 28), but then I give it to model  `res = model.predict(gray_image)`  and I got `Input 0 of layer "dense" is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1of input shape to have value 784, but received input with shape (None, 28)`

Comment: @user2640045, thanks, I solved this problem, I simply had reshape to (1, 28, 28, 1)

Comment: @TCArlen, thanks, u was right, that part of the code worked.